# PhpStorm xdebug won't debug

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I am learning php and use the PhpStorm IDE. In school we use XAMPP as server and xDebug as debug plugin. I have installed everything and i can "run" code but can't debug, when i start a session, the breakpoints seem to be ignored. There are some screenshot below.

Can someone help me please?

[image: code]

[image: webpage]

[image: phpinfo]

php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="E:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.1-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
```

xdebug_log:

```
Log opened at 2017-03-07 07:32:48
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///E:/xampp/htdocs/PHPStormProjects/test/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.1-dev" protocol_version="1.0" appid="4568" idekey="17172"><engine version="2.5.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2017 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///E:/xampp/htdocs/PHPStormProjects/test/index.php" lineno="4"></xdebug:message></response>

<- stack_get -i 6
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="6"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///E:/xampp/htdocs/PHPStormProjects/test/index.php" lineno="4"></stack></response>

<- run -i 7
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="7" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- run -i 8
Log closed at 2017-03-07 07:32:49
```

Comment: have you set xdebug in php.ini?

Comment: show your phpinfo() and phpstorm debugger tab

Comment: 1) Have a look at these videos/manuals first (in case if you have not seen them yet): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) Provide xdebug settings (prove that you have enabled and configured it)

Comment: 1) You have more than 1 ongoing PHP debug session already -- maybe it's active there on another debugger tab? Better close all before starting new one. You may also increase limit in PhpStorm settings 2) what xdebug log has to say about it? -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: I have tried to increase the limit and restarted PhpStorm but no debug... When i go to the xampp control panel and try to see the log of php but there are none.

Comment: 1) Here is where to enable logging: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 2) After you made these changes -- restart Apache and verify with `phpinfo()` output that logging is enabled 3) Once confirmed -- try debugging. When done -- share the log file.

Comment: i have done some searching myself and found that when I try to validate the debugger, it gives a 404. What could be the cause?

Comment: i don't know what did the trick but it now works.

I deleted the log of the xampp server and just started the whole thing up again maybe it was something with the "Start debugger" in chrome.

Thanks
Wim

Answer (score 0):

Install XDebug Extension for Google Chrome and enable debuging or set xdebug.autostart = 1 in your xdebug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what did the trick but it now works.

I deleted the log of the xampp server and just started the whole thing up again maybe it was something with the "Start debugger" in chrome.

Thanks
Wim