# xdebug doesn't see parent class

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to develop a little forum on PHP with MySQL. I'm using PhpStorm and xdebug.

I don't want to use any php libraries in my project so I don't use Composer with its' autoload and use just my own `spl_autoload_register()` function to load classes.

My forum works well but when I try to debug any class, xdebug can't find parent class so I can't make debugging:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Core\Model' not found in /Applications/AMPPS/www/php-mvc/App/Models/Themes.php on line 13
```

How can I change this xdebug behavior so it could see parent class?

UPDATE: I think I understood, I have used wrong url as "start url" in debug configuration of phpstorm, so this config used wrong controller method (index instead of show), so debugger never get to my breakpoint in method "show".

Comment: If this code works but fails during debugging only ... then please explain how do you debug this code. So far it sounds like you are trying to run/debug that class directly (so bootstrapping code/logic is missed) instead of debugging it normally.

Comment: In phpstorm I click inside my class file and use context menu with option - "Debug Theme.php" for example. If I configure phpstorm to debug all application and set breakpoint in for example Theme.php, then debugging never stop at this breakpoint. Thank you for your question, LazyOne. What do you mean by "instead of debugging it normally"?

Comment: *"What do you mean by "instead of debugging it normally"? "* I mean what you have described it as *"to debug all application"*. Right now you are doing it wrong and the error you are having is expected & correct. You need to place breakpoint in desired file and then launch whole app in debug mode -- once execution gets to the file with breakpoint it should stop.

Comment: I suggest go over these links in case if you have not seen them yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm. In particular I recommend Zero-config approach: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: I see. Problem is that xdebug never stops on the breakpoint. Thanks for these links. Some of theme I've seen already. I'm going to watch them all.

Comment: It has to be either misconfiguration of xdebug .. or some other xdebug related stuff (like -- different letter cases (upper/lower) when requesting file and on actual file system). Please also ensure that there is no symbolic links in the path. If they are present -- you will need to provide Path Mappings. In any case: 1) collect xdebug logs for such unsuccessful debug session https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 2) You may try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code (programmatic breakpoint).

Comment: But the very first step is -- ensure that xdebug is installed and configured. for that -- please provide `phpinfo()` output captured via browser -- at very least top table (including zend and xdebug part) and whole actual xdebug section.

Comment: I don't have xdebug section (I know how it should looks like) in phpinfo while have only at very least top table http://joxi.ru/p273edVuwpMl27

Comment: I've validated my configuration http://joxi.ru/a2XGyPvs6LxDmg as it was described in https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Validating+Your+Debugging+Configuration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531902/phpstorm-xdebug-wont-debug -- that's how xdebug section should look like (last screenshot). If you believe that it's configured correctly (you have made it working  elsewhere etc) then great. P.S. If breakpoint does not get hit in specific file -- try placing it in entry point file (`index.php`) and then step through file by file -- make take some time)

Comment: Oh, I think now it works! I think I understood, I have used wrong url as "start url" in debug configuration, so this config used wrong controller method (index instead of show), so debugger never get to my breakpoint in method "show". Thank You very much, @LazyOne !